# Listen to changes periodically in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-model

**Experience: Newbie**

I have initialize function like this

```
initialize: function(){
        this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.asyncRender);
    }
```

I want to listen to changes periodically,like for every 5 sec

I want something like this

```
setTimeout(function(){
            this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.asyncRender);
        }, 5000);
```

How to do this?

**Update:**

This is throwing error `updateValues not defined`

```
initialize: function(){
        this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.asyncRender);
        setInterval(function(){
            this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.updateValues);
            console.log("3 seconds");
        },3000)
    },
```

this is not throwing errors

```
initialize: function(){
        this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.asyncRender);
        this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.updateValues);

    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to listen periodically. You just register once in the initialize. If anything changes in the model, this.asyncRender will be called.

Change here means any attributes set or removed or modified.

Try calling

```
this.model.set("title", "A Scandal in Bohemia");
```

and see this.asyncRender be called.

**EDIT:**
If you want to manually poll for every 5 minutes, then you can check this.model.changed property. This is not advisable though.

http://backbonejs.org/#Model-changed

```
initialize: function() {
  var self = this;
  window.setInterval(function() {
    if (self.model.changed) {
      // Do your stuff
      // this.asyncRender();
    }
  }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: I want to listen for every 5 seconds, In my app, changes happens in every millisecond, i don't want to execute this every time, i want to execute only after 5 seconds

Comment: You can setTimeout to check this.model.changed property. If it is true, then the model is changed. Check http://backbonejs.org/#Model-changed

Answer (score 1):

Then you don't have to register model.change event ...

Just do

```
setTimeout(this.asyncRender, 5000);
```